# Apache ModRewrite strip part from request_uri in rewriteCondition

Tags: mod-rewrite

so basically I have a link in my html `domain.com/app/css/build/app-23471942834.css` however on the server the file actually lives in `/fs/current/public/css/build/app-23471942834.css`. Is there a way to check if a file exists in a `RewriteCondition`? The problem is that I basically need the `/css/build/app-23471942834.css` part to check, without the `/app`. Is there a way to remove this in a condition?

So I need:

- `domain.com/app/login` to be rewritten to `/fs/current/public/login`
- `domain.com/app/build/css/app-123523.css` to be rewritten to `/fs/current/public/build/css/app-123523.css`
- `domain.com/app/build/js/app-123523.js` to be rewritten to `/fs/current/public/build/js/build/app-123523.css`

I am using Laravel so within my `public` directory there is another `.htaccess` by default with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Sorry, but I really suck at htaccess files. Thanks for your help.

What I got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/fs/current/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /fs/current/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /fs/current/public/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**SOLUTION:**

I solved my issue like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|jpg|gif|png|js|svg)
RewriteRule ^app/(.+)$ /fs/current/public/$1 [L]
```

So all the rewrite only applies to css/jpg/gif/png/js/svg I think the issue I had before, was that the index.php file was rewritten by the script as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "need the `/css/build/app-23471942834.css` part to check"? Presumably `app-23471942834.css` never exists? Why do you need to check that the resource exists? Can't you just rewrite it if it matches the pattern? Or is this just an example of one such pattern and you have many different CSS and JS URLs/files like this?

Comment: Do you have multiple domains/hosts on the same webspace? If not then the `%{HTTP_HOST}` check is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?app/(css/build/app)-\d+(\.css)$ /fs/current/public/$1$2 [L]
```

Not sure exactly what you are after, but this will internally rewrite a URL of the form `domain.com/app/css/build/app-23471942834.css` to `/fs/current/public/css/build/app.css`.

If you need to check that the destination file exists before rewriting then you can add a *condition* before the `RewriteRule` (although I'm not sure why you would need to do this, as you'll get a 404 regardless). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/fs/current/public/$1$2 -f
```

**UPDATE#1:** From comments...

> I would need to rewrite anything that is not a file

Ah ok, that makes more sense. You can replace the above `RewriteCond` directive with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

That will only process the following `RewriteRule` substitution if the requested URL did *not* match a file on the filesystem.

**UPDATE#2:** From updated question...

A more general solution, after the existing `RewriteEngine` directive, try the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/fs/current/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^app/(.+)$ /fs/current/public/$1 [L]
```

This will only rewrite the request if a file of the form `<document-root>/fs/current/public/css/build/app-23471942834.css` or `<document-root>/fs/current/public/login` exists on the filesystem.

Comment: Hmm this sounds pretty good, however I would need to rewrite anything that is not a file to `/fs/current/public/`. Can you tell me how I can do this (PS: Updated the above example)

Comment: So what exactly is `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` would it not include the `app/`? Would that not check if `/app/build/css/app-123523.css` exists instead of `/fs/current/public/build/css/app-123523.css`?

Comment: Yes, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` would potentially include `/app/` (which I thought you were referring to in your first comment: "rewrite anything that is not a file"). The first `RewriteCond` checks the destination. I have updated my answer with a more general solution based on your updated question. (Although in your question, you state: "however on the server the file actually lives in `/fs/current/public/css/build/app.css`" - that doesn't include the numeric code?)

Comment: Hey, sorry, the missing numbers are an error. I updated the question again.
The bottom 2 rows work to redirect the general request, however your solution does not quite work (I guess, because the `/app` is still in there correct?)

I need it to be `/fs/current/public/build/css/app-123523.css` or for js `/fs/current/public/build/js/app-123523.js` (without the `/app`).

Comment: Yes, that is what **UPDATE#2** should be doing, removing `/app` from the  requested URL. You say it works to "redirect the general request", but "does not quite work"? In what way does it not "quite work" - is there another type of request, other than the "general request"?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no, this works `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /fs/current/public/index.php?/$1 [L]` to redirect app/login to the correct path, but somehow your solution for the file seems to nor work. :( I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can I provide more information?

How does it know that `$1` is only the filename and not `/app/filename.css`?

Comment: `$1` is a _backreference_ to the captured group (ie. `(.+)`) in the `RewriteRule` pattern. So, given a URL `/app/foo/bar.css`, `$1` will contain `foo/bar.css`, so the request gets rewritten to `/fs/current/public/foo/bar.css`. The additional _condition_ ensures that the rewrite only occurs if `<document-root>/fs/current/public/foo/bar.css` exists as a physical file on the filesystem.

Comment: Somehow I can not get this to work. However I solved my case by doing:    

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.de$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|jpg|gif|png|js|svg)
    RewriteRule ^app/(.+)$ /fs/current/public/$1 [L]

Comment: It would seem that the check to see if the file exists (ie. `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/fs/current/public/$1 -f`) is failing for some reason? Is the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` server variable set to the expected value (you appear to be checking the `HTTP_HOST` so you would seem to have multiple domains)?  Is `app-23471942834.css` a physical file on the filesystem, or is the request rewritten?

Comment: NO, sorry, I updated the question, the problem was not your rewrite, but that it also applied to the index.php file, because it was not specifying only the files that need to be rewritten like that, I think.